# Entityframework replaces field with null and throws exception?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I try to add a object to SQL Database with EntityFramework 6, it looks like this :

Table :

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jobb](
    [starttid] [datetime] NULL,
    [sluttid] [datetime] NULL,
    [rowversion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [service] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [jobb_key] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_service_jobb] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [jobb_key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Class that represent the table :

```
public class Jobb
{
    public DateTime? starttid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? sluttid { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] rowversion { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int jobb_key { get; set; }

}
```

Code that tries to add the new object to database :

```
            using (var context = new ServiceJobbContext(_settingsService))
        {

            var current = await context.ServiceJobb.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.jobb_key == serviceJobb.jobb_key);

            if (current == null)
                current = context.ServiceJobb.Add(serviceJobb);
            else
            {
                current.service = serviceJobb.service;
                current.sluttid = serviceJobb.sluttid;
                current.starttid = serviceJobb.starttid;
                current.jobb_key = serviceJobb.jobb_key;
            }
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return serviceJobb;
        }
```

I have checked thatthe jobb_key is set but still I get this exception when running SaveChangesAsync :

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'jobb_key',
>   table 'MyDB.dbo.jobb'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: This line `current.jobb_key = serviceJobb.jobb_key;` seems pretty useless as you already get `current` by its `jobb_key` being equal to `serviceJobb.jobb_key`

Comment: You are correct, removed, thanks. In this case it is however never running that part of the code, just the Add.

Comment: What is the value of `serviceJobb.jobb_key` on that line `current = context.ServiceJobb.Add(serviceJobb);`?

Comment: current is null so it will try to add the serviceJobb. In serviceJobb the jobb_key is set to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your key column `[jobb_key] [int] NOT NULL` is not null while you are trying to insert null value to it in insertion operation so you should change the key field to be insert able or make it identity to be inserted automatically.

so in this statement it fail to insert

```
current = context.ServiceJobb.Add(serviceJobb);
```

solution 1 :

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int jobb_key { get; set; }
```

to explicit insert it because by default it is `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` so EF pass it as null

solution 2: make it identity in the level table in DB

```
 [jobb_key] [int] NOT NULL  IDENTITY(1,1) ,
```

check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) also of auto generated properties in EF

Comment: Well, `public int jobb_key` cannot hold `null` anyway, right?

Comment: Im sure that the jobb_key field is set to a int value, I have dubble checked in debug.

Comment: entity framework might be assuming that your jobb_key field is an identity and therefore passing it AS NULL

Comment: try to add this attribute to you key in the entity [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Comment: Thanks, that workt, but it seems strange that this is standard procedure with EF? I need to set the jobb_key from kod, will the Identity solution still work?

Comment: you can check this link https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Add the `[Required]` attribute to the `not null` Fields and `[DatabaseGenerated]` to the rowversion:

```
public class Jobb
{
    public DateTime? starttid { get; set; }

    public DateTime? sluttid { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    [DatabaseGenerated]
    public byte[] rowversion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string service { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int jobb_key { get; set; }

}
```

Note: ValueTypes are implied to be `[Required]`

Comment: Well, `public int jobb_key` cannot hold `null` anyway, right?

Comment: Tried this, It makes some extra validations and it fails on rowevers(is not set). I need the SQL database to handle the rowversion(set and check).

Comment: If I remove ren required on rowversion I yet again get this exception : SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'jobb_key', table 'MyDatabase.dbo.jobb'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

And I can see that the jobb_key is set to 3 on the added object.

Comment: @Banshee is `jobb_key` ever modified? Is it 0?